# Motherboard or CPU Broken?

Tags: boot, cpu, motherboard, bsod, crash

Recently my PC started to bluescreen after about 15 seconds of uptime. After painstakingly narrowing the problem down to either the MB or CPU I am not sure which one is broken.

My PC specs:

- R5 2600
- MSI X470 Gaming Plus
- Sapphire RX 580 (8G)
- RAM Gskill AEGIS F4-3000 C16S-8GISB (x2)

Here is my progress until now:

1. tried to reset Bios etc, nothing changed
2. tried to install fresh Windows and Manjaro on the PC, both failed with several attempts
3. figured that my SSD might be broken, swapped it for another one, tried to install Manjaro this time, it worked
4. realized only one of my two RAM sticks are getting recognized (had a similar problem before RMA'd my motherboard because of this in 2019)
5. somehow got that fixed by first putting both sticks in single channel and then back into dual channel
6. system got really unstable, programs where crashing randomly, firefox often couldn't even play one video on YT from start to finish
7. tried to install Windows again, it failed again (I was tinkering to get LoL working through Lutris so I wanted to be sure it wasn't the problem)
8. updated the BIOS to newest version
9. tried to install Windows and Manjaro (with two or one RAM stick) both fail (This time Manjaro won't even boot from USB like before. It gets stuck in the bootscreen where the checks run right after something like [ok] loading graphic interface)
10. currently I am creating a new Windows bootstick with a new download of the media creation tool since the one I had on my laptop was a few months old, though I doubt it'll do anything

Does anyone have an idea where the problem is. Sadly I can't run any testing program since the system won't boot into OS (bios works fine though).

Comment: You could try using something like Ultimate Boot CD to try and test some thing. It loads a lightweight live environment with loads of tools.

Comment: Had something similar, but my PC would just randomly shutdown. I had an Intel i9 and it can be diagnosed with a tool from Intel to verify if the CPU is capable of doing all the specific calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I used USBCat to diagnose that one of my ramsticks where broken, sadly even with working ramsticks the system didn't like dual channel ram. I bought new ram and a new motherboard, because my motherboard had the same problem before. My system is running fine so far.